# Find an email's location in Outlook 2010 search

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook sends an email somewhere immediately upon arrival in the inbox.

When I search for it I can find it in search but cannot tell where it is. (I can locate a test message I sent but cannot find one that came in from someone else prior to my discovery that this was happening).

How can I determine the location of this particular email once I find it in search?

Thanx

Barry Austin

Comment: How and where do you search for these _lost_ emails? Did you create any filters? Are these emails treated as spam?

Answer (score 2):

Double-click the email found to open its message window. Open **File** menu. On the **Info** tab you will find the folder name next to the **Move to Folder** button (Current Folder).

Answer (score 0):

Open the found message from the Search list.

Press Ctrl + Shift + F to open Advanced Find

Click Browse

Scroll to see the folder tree